# How to change timezone in Date.now in mogodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My current MongoDB Schema is

```
currentTime : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
```

which gives me output as:

***"2022-03-20T09:28:44.000Z"***

this time is as UTC timezone but I want to change it to IST so I want to add five and a half hours to it, how can it be achieved?

I tried finding an answer for this but was not able to find any adequate solution, I am just a beginner any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance!